# Debug apk installation error in other mobiles

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I want to share my debug apk to testing team for testing. here app-debug.apk throws an error while installing in other mobiles. I am using my mobile(MI note 4) as an emulator and app is installed successfully.
But when I copy apk from ....\app\build\outputs\apk\debug path, that apk throws an error. like below

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![MY Android studio][2]][2]

My Android studio
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew3hT.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmeQ9.png

> android {
> compileSdkVersion 26
> buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
> }

```
{
        dependencies {
                    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
                    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            }
}
```

Note: In every time I share signed apk to client only, otherwise I used app-debug.apk in development.

Comment: see what's logcat says when you try to install the APK

Comment: only APK release version can be transferred and install

Comment: I have send debug apk to  mail.    when connect to USB , its working fine.

Comment: I am also face this issue. i am build 4.4 and share that's working fine. but above 4.4 mobile build share not working install time get error. but what reason i don't know but release version as working all version of mobile. Try this one.

Comment: i think they already have some version installed of same app, Right ??

Comment: Could you please before give minus(down vote), give a proper comment. Here i was not face this type of issues in previous. In every time  i share signed apk to client only, otherwise i used app-debug.apk in development.

Comment: @Rahul No, itsa new device or if it apk exist, i uninstalled

Comment: issue is that your debug apk not build properly. create again. and try again

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel , i have tried 5+ times, but same problem repeated, at  finally i have generated signed apk and share to testing team. its working fine( i.e not throw error while install)

Comment: Thanks to all. (But my problem is not solved)

Comment: might be u added some permission which is not supported by the testing device

Comment: Same here, except I run the app successfully on the phone via USB, but when I make an APK and install it manually it throws this error. Android developers made it really hard to debug installation errors on the actual phones. I have no idea what's next, I keep searching, maybe I find a solution. It is weird that they write about "adb" CLI commands in the documentation, but they don't write about where I can open the terminal where I could use these commands... People are talking about logcat, but I won't root (and possibly brick) my phone just to watch logs...

Comment: Ok, I figured meanwhile. On Windows 7 it is the "C:\Users\inf3rno\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools" directory you need and there run adb.exe from CMD. There you can do for example "adb devices". Note that it does not work with git bash. It is weird that the installer does not add it to path by default and I have to lookup a hidden folder to find it. It is far from being intuitive...

Answer (score 0):

Install multidex and then build the apk.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

i hope its work for you ...!

Answer (score 0):

On your Android device you need to enable USB debug or wifi debug in the `settings / developer options`. It depends on the Android version how you can enable developer settings.

On your PC you need to install the platform tools. For me it came with Android Studio by default, but you can install it from `Android Studio menu / Tools / SDK manager / SDK tools tab` currently. After that you need to add the `android_sdk/platform-tools/` directory to the PATH to be able to use `adb` without being in that directory. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb For me on Windows 7 the directory is `C:\Users\inf3rno\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`. Adding to PATH is not hard, the PATH is an environment variable you need to append it with the directory. It depends on the actual OS how you can do it. After that you can open terminal and type `adb devices`. After that you can choose the actual device id and type `adb logcat ${actual_device_id} > ~/android_log.txt` and try to install the APK file again. The `android_log.txt` should contain something like this with a lot of noise.

```
W/InstallAppProgress(25247): Replacing package:com.example.androidalert
D/ApplicationPolicy(  456): isApplicationInstallationEnabled
W/PackageManager(  456): verifying app can be installed or not
D/InstallAppProgress(25247): Installation error code: -15
I/InstallAppProgress(25247): Finished installing com.example.androidalert
```

For me it is weird, because it writes both error and installation finished and it asked if it should replace the previous installation even though it always wrote *"installation failed"* so far, but that is a different story... In my case error code -15 means it is a test only package, so I guess I have to make the APK differently for the production version.